# Citing the preface of a book written by a different author in ASA

Tags: citations, citation-style, social-science

As the title says, I'm trying to cite the preface of a book. The book is a new edition, and the preface was written by a different author. How do I cite that in ASA style? The closest I can think of is treating it as a book chapter, but that's also not quite right because the original author would be titled as the editor... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if there is a better "more correct" way to do this in ASA, but I would think you should cite it as a chapter with the appropriate author i.e., the one who wrote the section. This is how it is normally done in my field - often each chapter of a textbook has different authors.